# While loop Not Printing Correct Word in Guess game

Tags: python

How do I make the loop work so that it will end when you get it right  and ask the question again if you get it wrong?
When i guess wrong two or more times it will always say wrong no matter what.

```
import random;
import sys;
x = random.randint(1, 100);
print(x);
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100"));
if guess == x:
        print("correct");
        sys.exit()
while guess != x:
    print("wrong");
    int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100"));
    print(x);
    if guess == x:
        print("Correct");
        sys.exit()
```

Also what function records the number of times it loops. For example if I guess wrong 10 times then I want to print that I scored a 10.

Comment: I really recommend dropping the semi-colon at the end of lines - it's unnecessary, and worse, once you're used to reading Python code, it's confusing (you begin to expect it being a colon, which you do see often at the end of a line)

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to assign the second time around to the `guess` variable

```
while guess != x:
    print("wrong");
    guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100")); #look here
    print(x);
    if guess == x:
        print("Correct");
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing 'guess=' in the input line in the loop. To record number of times, just increment a variable in the loop.

[ADDENDUM]

```
import random;
import sys;
x = random.randint(1, 100);
print(x);
count = 1
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100: "));
while guess != x:
  count += 1
  guess = int(input("Wrong\nGuess a number 1 to 100: "));
print("Correct - score = "+str(100./count)+"%");
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with the increment a variable part?

Comment: import random;
import sys;
x = random.randint(1, 100);
print(x);
count = 1
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100: "));
while guess != x:
  count += 1
  guess = int(input("Wrong\nGuess a number 1 to 100: "));
print("Correct - score = "+str(100./count)+"%");
sys.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should change your codes to:

```
import random
x=random.randint(1,100)
score=0
while True:
    guess=int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100: "))
    if guess==x:
        print ("Correct!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Not correct!")
        score+=1
 print ("your answers was wrong {} times.".format(score))
```

Better statements,less codes. Cheers!

Comment: Also what function records the number of times it loops. For example if I guess wrong 10 times then I want to print that I scored a 10.

Comment: Define a variable equal to zero and upgrade the value of this variable after wrong answer, then outside of _while_ loop print that variable

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please check it as answer.

Comment: I don't think the asker is going to return.